# python auto install modules and pygame window

Tags: python, pygame

I have two questions about pygame and python:
One: It is using pygame in fullscreen mode and I was wondering how I can get other windows (google chrome, Safari, Mail, Thunderbird, Itunes) to go on top of the already fullscreen window. Two: Can I make Python install all the modules that the custom desktop will need without the user having to go and install them all themselves

Comment: For the fullscreen mode, choose borderless. http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a borderless screen that is the size of your desktop excluding the start menu etc. For the second question, just compile so the user doesn't need python. I have done this quite easily with py2exe, assuming you are running windows, I have heard py2app is good for mac, py2exe cant really be used easily on linux but with wine its programs seem to run fine.